# How to tell RoboVM to run a specific iOS device?

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I'm making a libGDX game and invoking RoboVM from Android Studio. It always starts iPhone 6 simulator and when I try to switch the device in the simulator it quits the program. I want to be able to test in iPhone 5 and iPhone 6+ simulators, but I have no idea how?

Can I pass some arguments to RoboVM or is there some other way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. With gradle: https://github.com/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin#project-properties

   The iOS Simulator launcher properties can be set by project properties via `gradle.properties` or `-P` command line parameter:

   - `robovm.device.name`: Set the device name property.

     - iPhone-4s: iPhone 4S
     - iPhone-5: iPhone 5
     - iPhone-5s: iPhone 5S
     - iPhone-6: iPhone 6
     - iPhone-6-Plus: iPhone 6 Plus
     - iPad-2: iPad 2
     - iPad-Retina: iPad Retina
     - iPad-Air: iPad Air
     - Resizable-iPhone: Resizable iPhone
     - Resizable-iPad: Resizable iPad
2. With RoboVM plugin: http://docs.robovm.com/getting-started/intellij.html#running-debugging
   [image: Run Configurations]